# Machine Learning with Keras: Different Validation Loss for the Same Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use keras to train a simple feedforward network. I tried two different methods of what I think is the same network, but one is performing significantly better. The first one and the better performing one is the following:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(384,))
dense = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")
x = dense(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(384)(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="simple_model")

model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='Adam')

history = model.fit(X_train, 
                    y_train_tf, 
                    epochs=20, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
                    steps_per_epoch=100, 
                    validation_steps=50)
```

and it settles on a validation loss of about 0.2. The second model performs much worse:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(384,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(384, activation='relu'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)

history = model.fit(X_train, 
                    y_train_tf, 
                    epochs=20, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), 
                    steps_per_epoch=100, 
                    validation_steps=50)
```

and this has validation loss of around 5. But when I do model.summary, they look virtually the same. Is there something wrong with the second model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that they are the same since second model has relu activation after last layer (384 units) and first doesn't. This might be the issue since default activation of the Keras dense layer is None.

Comment: I took out that final activation function and it worked much better! Do you have any idea why this would be the case? My intuition is that an activation function increases model complexity so should perform better, but is there a good reason why it performs better without the ReLU?

Comment: It depends on your problem but usually, the last layer activation depends on your target. For example, imagine that you are doing a regression problem and your target can have negative values. If you will put all on top of the last layer output, you will hurt model performance since relu will zero out negative values. I don't know what problem you have here but most likely that's what happened with your model.